# conflict with cached type during `assignContextualParameterTypes`

Tags: typescript

What kind of code might cause this error?

Is there a way to get the filename it was processing at the time?

```bash
$ tsc --noEmit

node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:96841
                throw e;
                ^
    
Error: Debug Failure. Expected [object Object] === [object Object]. Parameter symbol already has a cached type which differs from newly assigned type
    at assignParameterType (node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:64824:26)
    at assignContextualParameterTypes (node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:64789:21)
    at contextuallyCheckFunctionExpressionOrObjectLiteralMethod (node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:65191:29)
    at checkFunctionExpressionOrObjectLiteralMethod (node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:65170:13)
    at checkExpressionWorker (node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:66767:28)
    at checkExpression (node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:66669:38)
    at checkExpressionCached (node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:66373:24)
    at getReturnTypeFromBody (node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:64893:30)
    at contextuallyCheckFunctionExpressionOrObjectLiteralMethod (node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:65198:42)
    at checkFunctionExpressionOrObjectLiteralMethod (node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:65170:13)

Node.js v18.2.0
typescript-4.7.2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in TSC and was fixed by https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/49740

[This comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50773#issuecomment-1334397895) has advice on how to debug:

1. Run tsc with `--generateTrace traceOutputDir`
2. Then run `npx @typescript/analyze-trace traceOutputDir`

A work-around is often to an explicit type to a generic function that was trying to do type inference.